# AngularJS Directive isn't executing Jquery-ui menu

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to get a jquery-ui menu to work inside an AngularJS directive.

I have tried [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3apurq2h/) with an example of what I'm trying to do.

**html**:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController">
  <ul j-menu>
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li>Test 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**js**:

```
var myapp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myapp.directive("jMenu", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $(element).menu();
    }
  }
});

myapp.controller("mainController", ['$scope', function($scope) {}]);
```

The most perplexing piece is that I have [modified another 'working' fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guzwecf4/) to do exactly what I want to do but cannot replicate in my own fiddle nor in my own dev env.

What am I missing?!

Comment: missing `scope: {}` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that there's a problem with how `jsfiddle` is handling external resource with AngularJS, it keeps logging out `$injector` errors in the console. I've copied and pasted the external resources in a `plunker` and everything else in your first fiddle and it works just as how its supposed to be.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ECXAx6vnp4lVepCuhJp7?p=preview)**

Note: Since you've added jquery, all angular elements are also jquery elements. So by treating elements as such you can do this:

instead of

```
$(element).menu()
```

you can do this

```
element.menu()
```

Update:

As what [Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2237268/ali) pointed out, JSFiddle has the option to change the `Load Type` to `No wrap - in <body` in the `javascript` settings located at the `javascript` textarea's top-right corner.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/970z0m3t/)**

Comment: Very interesting find. After looking at my console window's output on my dev setup, I saw some errors that I thought were 'normal'. After correcting them, my local solution also worked. Thanks!

Comment: There is no issue with jsfiddle. Just change the load type in the javascript area to `No wrap - in <body>` and it will work.